# Subscribing to a topic returns nothing

Tags: json, robotframework, mqtt

I'm new to RobotFramework and MQTT. The main requirement for the broker is that only a valid JSON message should be published. So far I've been able to successfully publish my messages. 
I subscribe to the topic I posted to in PowerShell and I see that the message has been posted

However, When I try to subscribe and validate, in RIDE, I dont get any message returned.

E.g: *I was able to publish this as a retained message to the topic*:

```
Test/TestTopic
    {"schema": { "name": "XkvPYD2i", "version": 1 },"title": "XkvPYD2i","tags": "XkvPYD2i"}
```

*This code works*:

```
Publish Single  ${topic}    ${message}  ${qos}  ${Retained} ${broker.uri}
(Where the global file defines these values( as above) ${qos}=0)
```

*This code doesn't work*

```
@{messages}=    Subscribe   ${topic}    qos=${qos}  timeout=5   limit=0
log ${messages}
```

I expect to have the message (I posted above) returned and stored in ${messages}. But I get the following(from logs):

```
KEYWORD BuiltIn. Log ${messages}
Documentation:  
Logs the given message with the given level.

 Start / End / Elapsed: 20190219 14:57:53.909 / 20190219 14:57:53.910 / 00:00:00.001
 14:57:53.910   INFO    []
 20190219 14:57:53.907 :  INFO : @{messages} = [ ]
 20190219 14:57:53.910 :  INFO : []
```

Can anyone advise how can I make that work? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the link to the right MQTT library you used in this setup?